# Wordpress author profile page URL

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress blog here(http://muraliprashanth.me) everything seems to be working fine but the problem is after each post i am appending author information like the image below

[image: Murali Prashanth]

but when i click on the

> View all posts by Murali Prashanth hyperlink

it's redirecting me to this URL http://muraliprashanth.me/author/Murali%20Prashanth/ 
I don't know where to create the author profile page or does my wordpress theme supports author profile pages or not Please suggest me i am struggling to resolve this issue from past 3 months, Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's redirecting to the author's posts page, which in this case doesn't exist. Gives a 404 error. The WP slug is something like `murali-prashanth` with no spaces, so there is something wrong with that link. ¿Where did you get it? Anyway, make sure in all your posts the author is you. Regarding the profile, just create a template page with it.

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange site dedicated to Wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

These two links have the details about the author profile linking as well as template information. Have a look and see if you are able to fix it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_url

Comment: Thnx arun i'll check with this

Comment: but when i access direct author.php file it's throwing an error http://muraliprashanth.me/wp-content/themes/admired/author.php

Comment: There is some error at line number 8. See what is that or else paste it so I can see it

Comment: This is the sample template code from your url http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File

Comment: I understood what mistake you have made in accessing the author's page. You can't navigate to the place where it is present to access it. You must use some of the wordpress functions to use it. Try using the_author_link ()

Comment: where should i use the_author_link

Comment: Mostly at the end of the posts. Here is the brief description of that functions and suggestions for other related functions.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_link

Comment: what is the php page for post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21560/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-murali-prasanth)

Answer (score 1):

Try it. I 've given my author.php file for usage.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Author Archive pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
    if ( have_posts() )
        the_post();
?>

                <h1><?php printf( __( 'Author Archives: %s' ), "<span class='vcard'><a class='url fn n' href='" . get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) . "' title='" . esc_attr( get_the_author() ) . "' rel='me'>" . get_the_author() . "</a></span>" ); ?></h1>

<?php
// If a user has filled out their description, show a bio on their entries.
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ) : ?>
                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'avatar_size', 60 ) ); ?>
                <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'theme' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    rewind_posts();

    get_template_part( 'loop', 'author' );
?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```